# Connecting Monitor to TV via HDMI from computer

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, desktop-computer, cable

I have a mac with usb C and its connected to a monitor via a single usb C cable. The monitor acts as a dock for a bunch of usb, hdmi, ethernet connections to the mac. Is there a way to daisy chain that monitor to a TV?

TV runs on HDMI so could I use a displayport to HDMI, I've tried using a HDMI to HDMI from monitor to TV but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this - for several reasons.

1. HDMI doesn't daisy-chain, it must be DisplayPort right through.
2. Macs don't use DisplayPort MST.
3. to get a Mac to run two screens from a single Thunderbolt 3 interface, you must use Thunderbolt 3 right through, as TB3 can run two independent DP streams simultaneously.